# File upload error not detected by flash as3 with php

Tags: php, actionscript-3, file-upload

ActionScript 3 has a sophisticated way of uploading files with php. A common error (at list for me) is wrong url, so php can't allocate the file. This should generate an error since I put all those events, following the script suggested by Adobe. It's firing the COMPLETE event instead, so my idea is passing some returning info from php, writing a JSON. When I do a URLLoader + URLRequest it's work fine: the event return the answer from php by .target.data property, but making a fileReference.upload method with URLRequest, the same property returns null!

That's the events I'm using:

```
_fileReference.addEventListener(Event.CANCEL, canceledHandler);
_fileReference.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS,progressHandler);
_fileReference.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,ioErrorHandler);
_fileReference.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR,securityHandler);
_fileReference.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, httpHandler);
_fileReference.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
```

I need that the error events to fire or a way to get an answer from php, otherwise, I'm in the dark!

Answer (score 0):

First, AS3 doesn't have any php-specific functionality - although yes, it's quite competent at uploading files, and HTTP protocol.

If you're posting data to an incorrect URL, that's beyond the scope of AS3 — it's firing a COMPLETE event because it managed to post the data to the URL that you specified... whether the URL was correct or not.

What you probably should be using is the [HTTPStatusEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#event%3ahttpStatus).  The documentations says that it is: "Dispatched when an upload fails and an HTTP status code is available to describe the failure". I see in your code that you're already listening for that event, what code do you have in the event handler (httpHandler)?  Try tracing out the result whenever that event fires, hopefully (although I'm not sure) the event should indicate that you've posted to an incorrect url.  The event.status property should give you a good idea of what happened.  See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) for a list of valid status codes.

```
trace("status: " + event.status);
```